# Mysql select rows that DO and DO NOT

Tags: mysql, select

I have an INVOICES table:

```
person_id
price
issue_date
```

How can I select people who received invoice with issue_date '2013-07-%' AND received invoice with issue_date '2013-09-%' but DID NOT receive invoice with issue_date '2013-08-%' ?

Simply speaking: people who did not received invoice on August 2013, but did receive invoices before and after

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: Frankly I have no idea how to do it. I'm trying to google it since morning and I am just desperate now. I've tried some ugly things with UNION DISTINCT and WHERE NOT EXISTS, but nothing really worked. I am SQL newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> people who did not received invoice on August 2013, but did receive invoices before and after

this should do the trick:

```
select distinct(person_id) 
from INVOICES where 
  person_id IN 
    ( SELECT person_id from INVOICES where issue_date like '2013-07-%' OR issue_date like '2013-09-%' )
  AND person_id NOT IN
    (SELECT person_id from INVOICES where issue_date like '2013-08-%')
```

Comment: This select all the people who did not get invoice on 2013-08. Eg those who received their first invoice on 2014-03. I need to select people, who has been billed before and after 2013-08 but did not received invoice on this specific month

Comment: see edit - is that what you meant? (this would also select ppl who got the first in 2013-09, but you can filter them out accordingly

Comment: This catches people who received invoices *either* in July or September, but OP asked for people with invoices in *both*.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select july.person_id
from   (SELECT DISTINCT person_id
        FROM   INVOICES
        WHERE  issue_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31') july
       inner join
       (SELECT DISTINCT person_id
        FROM   INVOICES
        WHERE  issue_date BETWEEN '2013-09-01' AND '2013-09-30') sept
       on (july.person_id = sept.person_id)
       left join
       (SELECT DISTINCT person_id
        FROM   INVOICES
        WHERE  issue_date BETWEEN '2013-08-01' AND '2013-08-31') aug
       on (july.person_id = aug.person_id)
where  aug.person_id is null
```

This gets all persons with an invoice in July *and* an invoice in September but no invoice in August.

Also, it doesn't use the `IN` and `NOT IN` operations, which are known to be implemented poorly (or at least more poorly than explicit joins) in MySQL.